# Criteria for account to be used as aplication pool account

Tags: application-pool

Which account should be used as Application pool account while creating web application in sharpoint 2013? Or which accounts qualifies as application pool accounts?

Please can anyone tell me in simple words as I have read some articles and am a bit confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

It can be any domain user account. This account must not be a member of the Administrators local group on any computer in the server farm.
IIS uses it as the account to run application pool for your web application. So with claim-based authentication all requests to system resources will be done by with this account's identity.